# Interpolate a missing values using rows and columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

In Python Pandas, how should I interactively interpolate a dataframe with some NaN rows and columns? 
For example, the following dataframe -

```
             90  92.5        95       100       110       120  
Index                                                           
1            NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2       0.469690   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
3       0.478220   NaN  0.492232  0.505685       NaN       NaN   
4       0.486377   NaN  0.503853  0.518890  0.550517       NaN   
5       0.485862   NaN  0.502130  0.515076  0.537675  0.564383
```

My goal is to interpolate & fill all the NaN efficiently, I.E, to interpolate whatever NaN that is possible. However If I use

```
df.interpolate(inplace=True, axis=0, method='spline', order=1, limit=20, limit_direction='both')
```

it will return "TypeError: Cannot interpolate with all NaNs."

Comment: maybe because the second column is full of NaN. Also there is a row full of NaN. Could be trouble for some algorithm to interpolate that

Comment: Make sure `df.dtypes` are all of type `float64` and not `object` as the interpolation method would consider a `DF` filled with all `NaNs` if it falls under the latter case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this (thank you [@Boud for `df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899568/interpolate-a-missing-values-using-rows-and-columns-values/41899853?noredirect=1#comment70982511_41899853)):

```
In [138]: new = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all').interpolate(limit=20, limit_direction='both')

In [139]: new
Out[139]:
             90        95       100       110       120
Index
1      0.469690  0.492232  0.505685  0.550517  0.564383
2      0.469690  0.492232  0.505685  0.550517  0.564383
3      0.478220  0.492232  0.505685  0.550517  0.564383
4      0.486377  0.503853  0.518890  0.550517  0.564383
5      0.485862  0.502130  0.515076  0.537675  0.564383
```

Comment: Equivalent but more compact style `df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')`

Comment: @Boud, good point, thank you! I've totally forgotten about `.dropna()`... Yeah, it looks much better now

Comment: @MaxU thanks but as you cal see this yields same values for all NaN fields. Do you know if there is a way to actually do the interpolation. I guess the interpolation has to be done several times and each time it will have to find the best possible possible, i.e. row 5 column 92.5 at the first run.